# When is my chat room most active -- in general, not just this week?

Tags: support, chat

The info page for a chat room shows activity over the past day (by hour) and the past week (by chunk of day), like this:

[image: graphs from info page]

Is there a way to see data for a longer period of time, like the last month or the last quarter (or even the last year)?  I'd like to understand when a room is *generally* busy or quiet, not just when it was on a particular week.

I'm not asking about activity on the main site, which I can measure using SEDE.  SEDE doesn't have chat data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, those charts represent data for the past *month*, not the past week. The first one represents activity by hour for the days in that month, the second represents activity by 4-hour period for the weeks in that month. Critically, both charts represent *the same data* - it's just bucketed differently.

Thus, either one you look at, you're already getting what you want - you just didn't know it.

Note that [this isn't quite what I asked for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61166/show-user-room-activity-graphs-to-enable-productive-match-making), but I have to concede it's probably more useful (and, in the case of the charts for individual users, somewhat less creepy).

Given the purpose of this was to enable folks to see at a glance the best time to catch folks live in chat, it doesn't make much sense to use data any older than this; that said, it can occasionally be fun to see how activity in a chatroom has *changed* over time. Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to [scrape the chatroom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267051/scraping-the-chatroom).

Or, ask an employee:

[image: chart of user and message activity in The Factory Floor chatroom over the past 104 weeks]

Comment: Thanks!  We're trying to figure out a day + time that works for a recurring event, so the day-of-week information in the second chart is useful.